# Cannot exit fullscreen mode

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I was just testing the fullscreen mode, but I can't exit fullscreen.

How do you exit fullscreen?

My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Subclass QMainWindow to customise your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello fullscreen world")

        label = QLabel("Hello fullscreen world")

        # The `Qt` namespace has a lot of attributes to customise
        # widgets. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Set the central widget of the Window. Widget will expand
        # to take up all the space in the window by default.
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        
        self.shortcut_close_window = QShortcut(QKeySequence('F11'), self)
        self.shortcut_close_window.activated.connect(self.goFullscreen)
    def goFullscreen(self):
        if self.isFullScreen():
            self.exitFullScreen()
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowType_Mask)
            self.showFullScreen()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

If I run that, it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'exitFullScreen'`

I also tried changing `self.exitFullScreen()` to

```
self.hide()
self.show()
```

but that just hides the window and shows it again in fullscreen mode.
I also tried changing it to `self.showMaximized()`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs on showFullScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen): "To return from full-screen mode, call showNormal()."

E.g.:

```
def goFullscreen(self):
    if self.isFullScreen():
        self.showNormal()
    else:
        ...
```

You should remember to restore the window flags when restoring from full screen mode, e.g.:

```
def goFullscreen(self):
    if self.isFullScreen():
        self.setWindowFlags(self._flags)
        self.showNormal()
    else:
        self._flags = self.windowFlags()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.WindowType_Mask)
        self.showFullScreen()
```

Comment: that works, but the close button, minimise button, etc. are hidden. How do you stop that?

Comment: @cd-CreepArghhh I've updated the answer with code to get the buttons back